# Automatically reconnect to Bluetooth speaker

Tags: windows-7, audio, windows-8.1, bluetooth, speakers

I have two laptops, one runs windows 8.1 (Lenovo) and one runs windows 7 (Dell).

I have a Bluetooth speaker: [http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00JZVPGD6/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o03_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00JZVPGD6)

I notice that both machines can’t reconnect to the speaker after connection drops. 
They connect to the Bluetooth speaker just fine after booting. But if they lose the connection somehow, they will not connect to the Bluetooth speaker until I remove the device and add it again.

How can I solve this problem so that the connection can be restored, preferably automatically?

Comment: what's the bluetooth speaker, its the most likely culprit.

Comment: OK what if it's the speaker, what can you do about that except reconnecting? It probably has no interface for bluetooth.

Comment: Please add information on type of your speaker.

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00JZVPGD6/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o03_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Answer (score 1):

I suffered for many days with this problem that the windows will not be able to reconnect with my bluetooth speaker

finally I found a very crude and primitive solution. I have a small button in my laptop to put it in airplane mode. So if I switch off that button then the laptop switches off wifi and bluetooth.

when I switch it back on again, windows bluetooth gets reset and now it connects to the speaker fine.

so it is just another form of "control+alt+del" curse of windows

Comment: I use a same way. I turn Bluetooth function off and on again using the icon at the taskbar; it then connects to the device.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to do some additional testing. Perhaps you can try with your mobile phone Bluetooth audio service. If you find **the same behavior regardless of device type and manufacturer**, then it is high chance that the problem is in Bluetooth firmware of your speaker.

In other words, it could be possible that Bluetooth speaker doesn't support correct reconnection. If it is getting stuck somehow in the process, then no reconnection attempts (or other remedies) from computers can help.

Comment: this is my blue tooth speaker http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00JZVPGD6/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o03_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Comment: @KnowsNotMuch - I'm unable to find who is the manufacturer. Perhaps you can find it in attached manual. There, try checking their support page if there isn't a new firmware. Or check support forums there. But I'm afraid that those cheaper devices are not getting this level of support. It is possible that if the reconnection problem is here with any devices you connect (I encouraged you to test with some more), you will need to live with this problem as it is. If you find some answer, you are welcome to post it here (as another answer).