# Why bluetooth speaker often fail after a long time

Tags: audio, bluetooth, speakers

I connected my computer with my omni 10 speakers.

It works.

After a while it stop working.

The status is still connected but no sound come up.

To fix that I got to remove the bluetooth speaker and then try to connect again.

Then it works.

Why?

There is a similar question here.

[Automatically reconnect to Bluetooth speaker](https://superuser.com/questions/881292/automatically-reconnect-to-bluetooth-speaker)

However, unlike that problem the status of my bluetooth speaker is connected. Also the solution there of turning on and off bluetooth doesn't work.

Only removing the device and then walk to the speaker, press bluetooth button and then readd the device works.

After a while of not being used, the status remain connected but the speaker simply don't produce any sound.

The problem seems to be related to

https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/2758967/a-bluetooth-mouse-or-keyboard-fails-to-reconnect-after-being-left-idle

Comment: try to disable the `allow to save power` settings of your bluetooth adapter, I assume you are on Windows?

Comment: where is this "allow to save power"? settings?

Comment: device manager, select your bluetooth adapter NOT the speaker and you should find it there. at home on MacBook Pro, if you don't find it I can check tomorrow on Windows at work

Comment: I did that. It doesn't fix the problem. I think I should update the driver. But it's already the latest one.

Comment: try the speakers on another device. check for new firmware of speakers (I am not familiar with those speakers, but I have a BOSE which from time to time gets updated)